# core dump from dying multithreaded process

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-libraries, solaris, coredump

My multithread application (C++, SunOS) is dynamically linked with shared libraries. There are several threads in the program, some of them are from the libraries. One of such threads calls **exit()** and it results in generating core dump from another thread in shared library:

```
(dbx) where
  [1] 0x0(0xbeee0b30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1c00, 0x1, 0xbeee0b50), at 0x0
  [2] STLCollectionWrapper<std::vector<SM_Timer*,std::allocator<SM_Timer*> > >::empty(0xbeee0b30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1c00, 0xbca12200, 0x0), at 0xbee04690
  [3] GenPtrSortVec<SM_Timer,std::less<SM_Timer>,std::allocator<SM_Timer> >::isEmpty(0xbeee0b30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4fb0e0, 0xbd436b90), at 0xbee04424
  [4] sm_tmr_process(0x341000, 0x8e400, 0xbeeba00f, 0x1c00, 0x1, 0xbeee0800), at 0xbee03968
  [5] sm_nm_process_timeouts(0xbc67bf94, 0xbc67bf98, 0xbd4c3800, 0x0, 0xbca12200, 0xbee830f0), at 0xbee813dc
  [6] TimerThreadObject::poll(0x0, 0xbc67c000, 0x0, 0x0, 0xbedf1530, 0x1), at 0xbedf15f4
(dbx) thread
current thread ($thread) is t@null
(dbx) lwps
  l@1 LWP suspended in __SLIP.FINAL__A()
  l@3 LWP suspended in find_composition_start()
o>l@6 signal SIGSEGV in 0x0()
```

The stack frames 6-4 are from libA, frames 3-2 from libB. Frame 1 must have been called from C++ standard library (/usr/lib/libCstd.so.1?). As you see, this call failed.

At frame 4 the code called isEmpty() method of global object of type GenPtrSortVec. This object is located in the stack in the same module where the method sm_tmr_process() is defined. Later at frame 2 the code called empty() method of STL vector object. This vector is a field of GenPtrSortVec class.

I have the following questions regarding this issue:

1. **Why the first frame has address 0x0?**
2. Is it possible that libCstd had been unloaded from the dying process prior to cancelling all threads in the program? Note that libCstd was automatically loaded into the process as a dynamic dependency.

And two more questions about exiting from the process:

1. Is it possible that automatically loaded shared libraries had been automatically unloaded prior to cancelling all threads and destroying the global/static objects?
2. Is it possible that global or static objects had been destroyed prior to cancelling all threads?

Comment: **libA.cpp**:

`GenPtrSortVec< SM_Timer > timeoutList;

void sm_tmr_process(){
 timeoutList.isEmpty();
}`

**libB.h**:

[link](http://pastebin.com/PdvmfiTs)

Answer (score 2):

1.1 - possibly a null pointer call (see Jörgen)

1.2 - no

2.1 - no

2.2 - possibly

1.2/2.1: Shared libraries are loaded when the program is loaded in memory. The dynamic linker will then scan through all external references and fix them up. This is the process of dynamic linking. This won't be undone, i.e. no library loaded this way will be unloaded by the OS. The whole process image is trashed once the program terminates.

2.2 - that depends on your application. Initialization of global/shared objects can be problematic - see the static initialization fiasco. The same applies for destruction. The order in both cases is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 1: You probably called a NULL function pointer. Possibly not directly, but indirectly. Could you have overwritten the vtable of an object with zeros, and then called on of its virtual methods?

Comment: just a minor clarification: the vtable itself should usually reside in read-only memory (although I assume this is implementation-specific). What might be overwritten is the pointer to the vtable.

Comment: If the pointer to the vtable is overwritten, then it shouldn't crash at NULL. Dereferencing the vtable pointer should crash at the call site, right?

Comment: @Jörgen I'd say that depends. Dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefined behaviour, so everything is possible afterwards ;-) - if it is overwritten with 0, it should actually crash at the call site. If it is overwritten with anything else, you might find that the relevant pointe in the vtable points to NULL - at least that's my understanding this evening...

Comment: Could you please explain how the pointer to the vtable can be overwritten?

Comment: The pointer to the vtable is located "somewhere" in the object itself. Where it actually resides depends entirely on the compiler. For instance, if you were to `memcpy((void*)object_ptr, source_data, some_length)`, you would most likely overwrite it. I'm not implying you would do something like this directly, but if casting is involved, or writing to stack based arrays (and the object is created on the stack), it is quite possible to do it without being caught by the compiler...

Comment: this object `timeoutList` (please see the source code in my comment above) is not used in any containers, it is not casted to any types,  its memory is not overwritten and the object is not modified by assignment operators. Any other ideas why the pointer to inner object (returned by `stl()` inside `STLCollectionWrapper::empty()`) could be reset to 0? Note that this happens only when the process is exiting.